# How to re-center a map using jquery-ui-map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui-map

Using jquery-ui-map.

I am loading data through JSON with some marker and the latitude/longitude of the
new  center of the map (location finder application).

```
var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(data.origin.latitude, data.origin.longitude)

// adding the marker for the new origin works
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': origin});

// does not work
$('#map_canvas').gmap('center', '49, 7');

// does not work
$('#map_canvas').gmap('center', origin);

// does not work
$('#map_canvas').gmap('center', {'position': origin});
```

All of the three center calls fail:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
$.a.$.fn.(anonymous function)jquery.ui.map.js:46
b.extend.eachjquery.js:35
b.fn.b.eachjquery.js:28
$.a.$.fn.(anonymous function)jquery.ui.map.js:40
(anonymous function)@@geosearch:477
c.extend.handleSuccessjquery.js:144
c.extend.ajax.w.onreadystatechange
```

What is the canonical way here?

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('get','map').setOptions({'center':origin});
```

Also see this link:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapOptions

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways, either get the map and use the native setter:

```
var map = $("#map_canvas").gmap("get", "map");
map.setCenter(origin);
```

Or you use the plugin option setter

```
$("#map_canvas").gmap("option", "center", origin);
```

Comment: good  point about accessing  `var map = $("#map_canvas").gmap("get", "map");` then you have access to all methods Google Maps API provides!

Answer (score 1):

with panTo, you can re-center the map

```
jQuery('#map_canvas').gmap.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng('0.00','0.00'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use `'option'` before position centering...

...like example below (I used button click event and some other option):

```
$("#button").click( function(){
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.origin.latitude, data.origin.longitude);
$('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'center', latLng);
$('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 7);     
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {position: latLng,bounds: false});   
});
```

hope help you.